# Automating prompt using selenium and python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

Is it possible to automate even the prompt event which says ***open zoom meetings*** using selenium?, So we generally used selenium to automate on the **CHROME** webdriver to open a meeting link but we cannot click *open zoom meetings* button like in the screenshot below, is there a way to do it using ***selenium and python***?

Thank you.[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes its Possible to Automate the Prompt using Selenium and Python.

You just need to change the focus from the parent page to the Alert pop-up. It can be done using following code snippet.

```
alert = driver.switch_to.alert //(driver is basically your webdriver) then switch_to.alert is used change focus from current page to alert.
```

And to Accept the popup you can use

```
alert.accept()// To Accept the meeting link.
```

or

```
alert.dismiss()// To Cancel the Pop Up.
```